# MySQL time between comparison past end of day

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I have a query that is not working for me in some instances and I think it's because the time wraps past the end of day in some cases such that the end time is less than the start time.  Here is the query.

```
SELECT reminder_cfg.id, default_time, day_prior, timezone 
FROM reminder_cfg, uc_users 
WHERE reminder_cfg.id = 5 
AND reminder_cfg.id = uc_users.id 
AND default_time BETWEEN TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AND TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

This has really been kicking my but for a couple of days now.

This is part of a Perl script that I'm sure there is a better way to do, but I'm stumped.

Comment: What is the data type of `default_time`? Is it `TIME` or `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 0):

Using [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to add two dates.

```
SELECT reminder_cfg.id, default_time, day_prior, timezone 
FROM reminder_cfg, uc_users 
WHERE reminder_cfg.id = 5 
AND reminder_cfg.id = uc_users.id 
AND default_time BETWEEN TIME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)) AND TIME(DATE_ADD(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR))
```